# PHP Simple modification/correction

Tags: php, dynamic, hyperlink, breadcrumbs

I got this code from someone, it's almost perfect to create a dynamic breadcrumb, but there just a little glitch because it echoes two dividers before the breadcrumb:

```
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    echo ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),'>' . $crumb));
}
```

it echoes:

">>content>common>file"

what I want it to look like is

"content>common>1"

and also I will deeply appreciate if someone can tell me how can I add links for all the items in the array except the last one (file)?

Thank you so much everybody, this website really helped me a lot to learn php by examples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this will do:

<strike>//get rid of empty parts
    $crumbs = array_filter($crumbs);</strike>

```
$result = array();
$path = '';
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    $path .= '/' . $crumb;
    $name = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "), $crumb));
    $result[] = "<a href=\"$path\">$name</a>";

}

echo implode(' > ', $result);
```

**Updated**

```
$result = array();
$path = '';
$num = count($crumbs);
for ($j=0; $j<$num; $j++) {
    $crumb = $crumbs[$j];
    if ($crumb == '') {
        continue;   
    }
    $path .= '/' . $crumb;
    $name = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "), $crumb));
    if ($j < ($num - 1)) {
        $result[] = "<a href=\"$path\">$name</a>";
    } else {
        $result[] = $name;
    }
}

echo implode(' > ', $result);
```

Comment: It works, how can I remove the link from the last item? (file)
Thanks!